# Proving that $f(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(z+re^{it})dt$ has no local minima or maxima

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I am asked to show that $$|f(z)| \le max_{\gamma} |f(z+re^{it})|$$ and I've done that proof. I'm stuck on proving that $|f(z)|$ has no local maxima (within its domain of analyticity) or minima (assuming f is analytic and never zero on it's domain).

For reference, this pertains to the Cauchy Integral Formula, particularly the case where $z$ is a point in the center of the circle $\gamma$. This case yields:
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(z+re^{it})dt$$

I'm just at a loss for a way to put all this together. I'm not asking for the answer, just some place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, suppose $|f(z)|$ has a maximum at $z_0$ - that means the value at $z_0$ is strictly bigger than any value of $|f(z)|$ on any small neighborhood of $z_0$, and in particular a small circle around $z_0$. But this contradicts the inequality you began your question with. For local minimum, apply the same argument to $1/f$.

Comment: Thank you. Why would I use $1/f$ when proving the minimum case?

Comment: because a local minimum for |f| is a local maximum for |1/f|. note that my argument for f only shows no local maximum, it doesn't show no local minimum. I need to apply it to 1/f. and that's why you had to assume f is never zero, because otherwise f can have a local minumum (e.g take f(z)=z).

Comment: Okay, I get it! Thanks again!

Comment: We can use this to show that a non-constant polynomial $P$ has a zero. As $|P(z)|\to \infty $ uniformly as $|z|\to \infty$, let $R>0$ with $|z|\geq R\implies |P(z)|>|P(0)|$. So  $\inf_{z\in C}|P(z)|=$ $=\min (|P(0),\;\inf _{|z|\leq R}|P(z)| \;)=$ $\inf_{|z|\leq R}|P(z)|$. But the continuous function $|P(z)|$ attains its minimum on the compact set $\{z:|z|\leq R\}.$